# Do I need to apply critical security patches again after Magento version upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, patches

Magento got couple of critical security patches few days ago and I installed those patches. I now need to upgrade to Magento 2.4.3-p1 and I was wondering do I need to apply the patches again or are they included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the security bulletin, https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-12.html the 2.4.3-p1 need also the patch.

As you make the patching on vendor subfolder, you need to apply them again against the new version